# Label font doesn't apply when using TemplateBinding in maui

Tags: c#, fonts, maui, maui-windows

I'm learning MAUI and this binding stuff is pretty tricky still...

I have a XAML like this:

```xml
<ScrollView Grid.Row="1"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Default"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
    <HorizontalStackLayout RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="MenuCategories"
                           x:Name="foodTypeStack"
                           VerticalOptions="Start"
                           Spacing="3">
        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton Content="{Binding .}">
                    <RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>

                                <Border x:Name="dishTypeContainer"
                                        MinimumWidthRequest="80"
                                        MaximumHeightRequest="140"
                                        Padding="8,0,8,0"
                                        Stroke="Transparent">
                                    <Border.StrokeShape>
                                        <RoundRectangle CornerRadius="20,20,20,20" />
                                    </Border.StrokeShape>

                                    <Label x:Name="dishTypeTextLabel"
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                           Text="{TemplateBinding Content.Name}"
                                           FontFamily="Icons"
                                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                </Border>

                                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                    <VisualStateGroupList>
                                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CheckedStates">
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Checked">
                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                    <Setter TargetName="dishTypeTextLabel"
                                                            Property="Label.TextColor"
                                                            Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                                    <Setter TargetName="dishTypeContainer"
                                                            Property="Border.BackgroundColor"
                                                            Value="{StaticResource DarkSeaBlue}" />
                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                            </VisualState>
                                            <VisualState x:Name="Unchecked">
                                                <VisualState.Setters>
                                                    <Setter TargetName="dishTypeTextLabel"
                                                            Property="Label.TextColor"
                                                            Value="{StaticResource LightGray}" />
                                                    <Setter TargetName="dishTypeContainer"
                                                            Property="Border.BackgroundColor"
                                                            Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                                </VisualState.Setters>
                                            </VisualState>
                                        </VisualStateGroup>
                                    </VisualStateGroupList>
                                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </RadioButton.ControlTemplate>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
    </HorizontalStackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In the .cs file i have this type of binding:

```cs
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    var foodTypes = await menuDatabase.GetFoodTypeListAsync();
    BindableLayout.SetItemsSource(foodTypeStack, foodTypes);
}
```

The **Icons** font for the label used on the RadioButtonTemplate is a *Fontello* font.

The problem is that the font in that label doesn't apply. It worked before I started using the Binding expression.

MauiProgram.cs file:

```cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .UseMauiApp<App>()
        .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
        {
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
            fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            fonts.AddFont("Fontello.ttf", "Icons");
            fonts.AddFont("Rubik-Light.ttf", "RubikLight");
            fonts.AddFont("Rubik-Regular.ttf", "RubikRegular");
        });

    builder.Services.AddSingleton<MauiAppTestDatabase>();

#if DEBUG
    builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif
    return builder.Build();
}
```

This is one of the strings that use on the label:

```
&#xE801; Drink
```

Comment: Have you followed these steps to use a font family? [Fonts in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/fonts)

Comment: May I ask what is the exact value for label text? Have you checked that value?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I added the file where I configure the fonts

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT Added one of the strings too

Comment: So it can only show the string '&#xE801;' not the icon.,right?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT yes

Comment: Then that's not the issue with TemplateBinding. I think the below answer gets to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the font icon string in C#, you need to use the following unicode notation:

```cs
public string MyIcon { get; } = "\ue801";
```

This should be the equivalent of writing `&#xE801;` in XAML.

With this, you should be able to see the font icon instead of the string when using it in a binding expression.

You can check the C# unicode notation for each icon here by uploading the font: https://andreinitescu.github.io/IconFont2Code/

***Note** that `&#xE801; Drink` is not a valid value for a label using an icon font, because the  `Drink` part is not found in the font. Depending on the platform, it may still be shown, but it's not guaranteed. If you need to display an icon and text, you should work with two separate labels each with a different FontFamily set - one for the icon and one for the text.*

Comment: It works if I use a class, but what if I want to retrieve the icon string from the database?
Because if i retrieve the \ue801 from the sqlite database i don't get the icon applied

Comment: What do you mean? How do you access the database? Normally, entities from a database are represented by a DTO class in code.

Comment: nothing sorry, I was writing directly on the database the value "\ue801"